# Gradle/Groovy syntax confusion

Tags: gradle, groovy

Can anyone explain/comment on this fraction of Groovy code?

```
task copyImageFolders(type: Copy) {
    from('images') {
        include '*.jpg'
        into 'jpeg'
    }

    from('images') {
        include '*.gif'
        into 'gif'
    }

    into 'build'
}
```

More specifically about the [from method](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:from(java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure)).
Is this the

```
from(sourcePaths)
```

or the

```
from(sourcePath, configureAction)
```

If its the one with the 2 arguments, why it’s written this way and not something like:

```
 from('images', {
     include '*.jpg'
     into 'jpeg'
 })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is it's calling `from(sourcePath, configureAction)`.

Groovy has optional brackets in a number of cases and accepts the last parameter (if it's a closure) outside of brackets and in this case that's the closure that you're passing to `from()`.

[This](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/11/groovy-goodness-passing-closures-to.html) is a good blog post explaining the different ways a closure can be passed to a method in Groovy if you want more examples and [this](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/10/groovy-goodness-optional-parenthesis.html) offers more examples of optional brackets in general.

Answer (score 5):

It's [Syntactic Sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), to make things easier to read (very useful for Gradle configuration)

In this case it's all about [parentheses](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses).

> When a closure is the last parameter of a method call, like when using
>   Groovy’s each{} iteration mechanism, you can put the closure outside
>   the closing parentheses, and even omit the parentheses:

```
list.each( { println it } )
list.each(){ println it }
list.each  { println it }
```

In your case, everything below is working fine :

```
from('images', {
    include '*.jpg'
    into 'jpeg'
})

from('images') {
    include '*.gif'
    into 'gif'
}

from 'images', {
    include '*.gif'
    into 'gif'
}
```

Comment: Am I the only one who finds this vast array of syntax options __harder__ to read?